# Vitest fails to load package ([vite-node] Failed to load meteor/meteor)

Tags: node.js, testing, meteor, vitest

I set up a new meteor project with TypeScript and installed vitest.

When I run vitest though, I get the following error:

```
FAIL  tests/main.test.ts [ tests/main.test.ts ]
Error: [vite-node] Failed to load meteor/meteor
```

The test is straightforward:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { describe, test, expect } from 'vitest'

// ---

describe('replay', function () {
    test('package.json has correct name', async function () {
        const { name } = await import('../package.json')
        expect(name).toBe('replay')
    })

    if (Meteor.isClient) {
        test('client is not server', function () {
            expect(Meteor.isServer).toBe(false)
        })
    }

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
        test('server is not client', function () {
            expect(Meteor.isClient).toBe(false)
        })
    }
})
```

The repository is publicly available here: https://github.com/repetitioestmaterstudiorum/replay

I don't understand why vitest can't import meteor. It's declaration is global thanks to `node_modules/@types/meteor`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are having is happening probably because you are calling vitest alone.

To test the meteor app you should use `meteor test --driver-package meteortesting:mocha`
As in passing, the driver will be used to test the application.

Vitest is also an assertion lib, so it would possibly be able to run in your app, but I was not able to make it work on my machine yet
for more details, check meteor [docs on tests](https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#running-full-app-tests)
also, if you may need something else, you can reach out to us in the issue section in the Meteor GitHub [repo](https://github.com/meteor/meteor)

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your message. Indeed, it appears as if that's the problem. 
With this post, I'm trying to find out why I can't use vitest normally inside a meteor app, and potentially even find a solution to do it anyway. 
I checked the tests before publishing my question, and I saw that there is no driver-package for vitest. 
Ideally, I'd like to be able to run tests with vitest normally (not meteor calling vitest and using it just as assertion library). Could you explain why that's not currently possible?